# Allow Hebrew letters in regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, unicode

I  am working with C# and ASP.NET, and in my web application, I have a text box for registration where I allowed the user to input only letters using this regex:

```
Regex.IsMatch(to_check, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$")
```

I want to allow Hebrew letters, too. I would allow Unicode but I want only the Hebrew letters to be available.

Hope you could help, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the Unicode Hebrew named character class `\p{IsHebrew}` to your custom character class:

```
 Regex.IsMatch(to_check, @"^[a-zA-Z\p{IsHebrew}]+$")
```

Here is a full list of such [named classes supported by .NET regex engine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SupportedNamedBlocks).